# hiding tableView.tableFooterView causes my section headerView to disappear

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableViewController with one section.  I have added a UIView directly to the tableView in storyboard and set outlets to my tableViewController for that view (headerView) and it's contents which are a segmented control and a searchBar.

In the tableView delegate methods I have the following for my header:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    return headerView
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 88
}
```

Everything is working fine except that there is no separator for the very last row of my tableView.  This is expected and the workaround for me has always been the following in viewDidLoad:

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
self.tableView.tableFooterView?.isHidden = true
```

For some reason, these two lines of code cause my headerView to completely disappear from the table.

I could create a tableViewCell and use that as my tableView header but there is a lot of delegation required for the searchBar and segmented control and that leads to other problems.  Mainly that the searchBar wants to resignFirstResponder every time I reload my tableView.  Again there are workarounds for that but it all starts to get a bit messy.

Just wondering why my headerView is disappearing and what I could do about it.

Comment: remove this line and try : self.tableView.tableFooterView?.isHidden = true

Comment: if I just have self.tableView.tableFooterView?.isHidden = true the headerView disappears and there is no separator on the last cell

Comment: it's as though the view I dragged into storyboard is somehow treated as a footerView for the table.

Comment: Check whether that view that you dragged acts as footer or header in IB

Comment: The view I dragged is titled Header View.  Not sure how to just have a view in the tableView without it being a Header View or Footer View.  Nevertheless it is a Header View apparently.

Comment: Can you share screenshot of your IB so that we can get an idea whether it acts as headerView or footer view

Comment: screen shot has been added above

Comment: add one cell in storyboard and check that at where  change your headerView .

Comment: adding a cell puts the headerView underneath the added cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove that header view from tableview and add it on UIViewController i.e directly drag them adjacent to `first responder` and `exit`. Then using IBOutlet you can use it as Section view. Here it is being treated as footer view as well.

[image]

Comment: removing the delegate methods removes the header.  It is acting as the header for the section and not the tableViewHeader

Comment: actually your header view is acting as footer view here as well

Comment: yes, you are right and that explains why it is disappearing.  I guess I have to add a cell for the header and use delegation.

Comment: wow.  thanks so much.  this works perfectly and saves me all the delegation.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you assign the new UIView object to table header view

If you want to toggle table header then you have to follow below step

1) keep the reference of you view which you want to set in table header

**UIView footerView = your storyboard referance**

2) when you want to hide then just assign nil to table footer

**self.tableView.tableFooterView = nil**

3) Now when you want to show then again assign your refence view

**self.tableView.tableFooterView = footerView**

Comment: I want to hide and keep hidden the tableViewFooter so that I can always have a separator on the last row of the tableView.  I don't understand why assigning nil to the footer also assigns nil to the header.